# How to implement If device width exceeds maximum width of normal Mobile devices then Use different Margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mobile friendly website, and It woks fine in Mobile devices, but when viewed from tab or any greater width device then the input  fields gets position itself at top. 
Is there any solution to run code that check the device width and if it is more then the normal width of mobile device then change the current margin-bottom:50% to margin-bottom:20%; and If it is smaller then major device ( for eg Bar phone ) then, increase margin bottom from 60% to 80%.

My current css is...

```css
div {
   position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 85%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 95%;
height: 100px;

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: depending on url content you want to load different webview in fragment 2?

Comment: @iamdeowanshi yes, instead of writing same code as I have done in Fragment 2....I would like to get string and if String1 equals to  Url1, pass SourceUrl = myurl.com else String2  equals to Url2, Source Url = myurl2.com else String3 equals to Url3 then SourceUrl = myurl3.com and on Webview loadurl(SourceUrl)....Something Like this. But I don't know how to put all this in Code.

Comment: as I can see, you have multiple buttons in your fragment 1 which are responsible for sending different urls to fragment 2. Still to fullfill your requirement in fragment 2 you can use switch block

Comment: @iamdewanshi yes I used the switch and It is working now. Thanks.